# OpenWRT fails to update opkg

Tags: package-management, openwrt

I have recently put OpenWRT on a Netgear rooter, which is connected to the modem. Web access through Linux (traceroute) / Firefox works perfectly, although with a few failed connections here and there and a slightly slower speed compared to direct modem hookup.

But when I try to open the LuCI interface, there is no list in "Software" of packages available to install.

```
$ opkg update
```

and any other related command run directly via root@ results in failed connections and

> ```
> opkg_download: Failed to download http://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/19.07.1/packages/mips_24kc/packages/Packages.gz, **wget returned 4.**
>
> opkg_download: **Check your network settings and connectivity.**
> ```

(goes for all packages)

I'm using stubby in the network presets in 127.0.0.1 to deal with DNS request encryption. Also, I've turned on SSH connection with public key to access the LuCI and modifications are restricted to LAN access only with pw prompt.

Since I can ping websites in CLI and use the browser with no issues whatsoever, did I lock up my OpenWRT router presets to the point where it can't access package lists?

Neither in LuCI nor via direct installation in the CLI of the router can I install packages.

I tried manually downloading the packages via the links prompted and upload them in LuCI manually, but that failed as well.

---

to – LinuxSecurityFreak

Thank you for commenting! I have IPv6 enabled right now. You mean I should disable IPv6 altogether?

I've installed stubby to encrypt DNS traffic in the network settings of my computer.

Can't really tell which WAN settings you mean though. My ISP modem is a Fritzbox and I've hooked my Router up with a regular LAN output from the modem. It runs perfectly on the browser so far, however, I can't download or manage any packages via LuCI interface or in command line.

Thanks for your advice

Comment: I use OpenWrt but the problem is, I am only a user. Let me make sure: IPv6 is disabled? + What do you mean with _stubby in the network presets in 127.0.0.1 to deal with DNS request encryption_?

Comment: I believe I might know this error, I think I encountered it myself, please do screenshots of WAN settings (hide your public things if any).